# Playframework: how to batch multiple GET requests

Tags: scala, playframework, url-routing

Say we have a PlayFramework application with the following routes:

```
GET /a controllers.App.doA()
GET /b controllers.App.doB()
GET /c controllers.App.doC()
```

Now we want to provide a additional route:

```
GET /multi controllers.App.doMulti(requests: Seq[String])
```

Which basically returns the combined results of the urls requested in `requests`. Something like:

```
def doMulti(requests: Seq[String]) = Action {
  Ok( Json.toJson(
    requests.map {
      url => ws.url(url).get().map {
        response => response.body 
      } 
    }
  ))
}
```

Where requests will typically be like `requests=Seq("/a", "/a", "/c", "/a")`, so calls to above routes. I guess there should be some way to internally route without having to make a http call via WS.

Like:

```
def doMulti(requests: Seq[String]) = Action {
  Ok( Json.toJson(
    requests.map {
      url => INTERNALLY_ROUTE(url).map {
        response => response.body 
      } 
    }
  ))
}
```

So `INTERNALLY_ROUTE(url)` would be the *inverse of the reverse routing* operation, mapping a url to the result of the request. So actually just routing. But I don't see how to do this using the play framework.

I tried injecting `Router` into my controller, but that gives circular dependencies.

Comment: I'm really curious to know what problem you are trying to solve. Anyway, you can inject the `play.api.inject.RoutesProvider` to break the cyclic dependency, as suggested by [Guice docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies#break-the-cycle-with-a-provider) and then access the `play.api.routing.Router`. After that, `Router` has a `handlerFor` method that you can use to get the `play.api.mvc.Handler` for a given `play.api.mvc.RequestHeader`.

Comment: Basically i want to be able to embed GET results into my response (which may be a more complicated json object than just a array of batch results), but you are right the simplest use case is batch results, and the hint to use `RoutesProvider` together with the ideas of @DmitriyYefremov should get me running. Thanks!